# I have joined two tables (Policy and Vehicle) in a one to one relationship. I want to get records from vehicle where vehicle.policy is null

Tags: php, database, sqlite, symfony, web

I am creating a Form form Policy where i want show those vehicles are not already used or associated with policy since its a one to one relation ship, and i am using query_builder for this purpose but i am not getting filtered results.

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($policy)
    ->add('vehicle', EntityType::class,[
          'class'=>Vehicle::class,
          'label' => 'Vehicle Plate',
          'query_builder' => function (VehicleRepository $vr){
          return $vr->createQueryBuilder('vehicle')
                 ->andWhere('vehicle.policy IS NULL');
           }])
```

But i am getting this error

A single-valued association path expression to an inverse side is not supported in DQL queries. Instead of "vehicle.policy" use an explicit join.

Comment: You need a left join for that.  What is the ORM, Doctrine?   I see DQL which is doctrine,  PS I hate doctrine ... lol  This looks more like a form builder (I don't use symphony) and not so much like the doctrine code I have seen.  But yea you'll need a Left Join, instead of Inner Join (Join) for this.  I don't see how the Join is done here so I am not sure how to help with it,  sorry.

Comment: Yes its Doctrine

Comment: Ok left join, can you tell me the query, even in SQL?

Comment: I don't know the schema, so I don't know what any of the fields are named, nor what data type or data they contain.  Basically `SELECT * FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.t1_id WHERE t2.t1_id IS NULL.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($policy)
->add('vehicle', EntityType::class,[
      'class'=>Vehicle::class,
      'label' => 'Vehicle Plate',
      'query_builder' => function (VehicleRepository $vr){
             return $vr->createQueryBuilder('v')
             ->leftJoin('v.policy', 'policy')
            ->where('policy is NULL');
       }])
```

Comment: actually i have used this, getting the same result = A single-valued association path expression to an inverse side is not supported in DQL queries. Instead of "vehicle.policy" use an explicit join.